# Packed together input boxes form style

Tags: html, css

I'm wondering if there is an official name for this style of the form: https://www.tumblr.com/login OR https://www.tumblr.com/register
where the input boxes are packed together with a line in between, and if so is there an existing library I can use to make these forms?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no specific name for this type, at least not that I know of. It's just made using CSS styling.

Something along these lines is what tumblr uses:

This CSS

```
.signup_form {
background: -moz-linear-gradient(center top , #DDE5ED 0px, #F2F3F4 100%) repeat scroll 0 0 transparent;
border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
border-radius: 8px 8px 8px 8px;
box-shadow: 0 1px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.36) inset, 0 1px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.15);
margin: 0;
overflow: hidden;
padding: 0;
position: relative;
width: 245px;
}

.signup_form .row {
border-top: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12);
position: relative;
}
```

And this HTML

```
<div id="signup_form" class="signup_form">
    <div class="row">
        <label>Email</label>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <label>Password</label>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Its just a css code! You should use these codes:

```
.class {
    border-bottom: 1px solid gray;
    border-top-right-radius: 5px;
    border-top-left-radius: 5px;
    ...
}
```

You can change "top" to "bottom" and "right" to "left".